# GAE How to print items stored in ndb.LocalStructuredProperty

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

Using the example from the Docs but using LocalStructuredProperty:

```
class Address(ndb.Model):
    type = ndb.StringProperty() # E.g., 'home', 'work'
    street = ndb.StringProperty()
    city = ndb.StringProperty()

class Contact(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    addresses = ndb.LocalStructuredProperty(Address, repeated=True)

guido = Contact(name='Guido',
            addresses=[Address(type='home',
                               city='Amsterdam'),
                       Address(type='work',
                               street='Spear St',
                               city='SF')])
```

EDIT:
This is actually how I am trying it with my model:

```
guido = Contact(name='Guido')
a = Address()
a.type='home'
a.city='Amsterdam' # etc etc..
guido.addresses.append(a)
guido.put()
```

Now say tomorrow I want to print out the items in addresses, I have an contact_id passed in a url from a web page and I try the following in a handler:

```
    contact_id = self.request.get('contact_id')
    contact = Contact.get_by_id(int(contact_id))
    logging.info("=====start contact addresses report===========================================")
    for item in contact.addresses:
         logging.info(item.type)
         logging.info(item.city)
    logging.info("=====finish contact addresses report===========================================")
```

I have looked at most of the SO ndb questions but cannot see anything that answers this.
I read in docs that data is stored in opaque blob, and i have tried various ways of trying to access the items. 
I ultimately want to be able to add, edit and subtract items, Just for the record I am using this property as it hopefully will be "cheaper" in billing - but i can't test it until I have my app up and running.
I know I am missing something basic here, Any help appreciated.

Comment: try removing the `[0]` for the addresses

Comment: thanks Jimmy, my model is obviously different from this but the structure is similr nd i can't seem to get it to show data. Maybe its the way i'm constructing the data prior to put()

Answer (score 1):

It appears the problem was that I had guido.put instead of guido.put()
Everything looks ok when you inspect - its in memory then. But when you try and retrieve at
a later point, you will only get contact.addresses[[]].
A small mistake that has wasted my time.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the following code as is and you'll see that the items stored in `ndb.LocalStructuredProperty` are being read properly:

```
import webapp2
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class Address(ndb.Model):
  type = ndb.StringProperty()
  street = ndb.StringProperty()
  city = ndb.StringProperty()

class Contact(ndb.Model):
  name = ndb.StringProperty()
  addresses = ndb.LocalStructuredProperty(Address, repeated=True)

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    guido = Contact(name='Guido',
                    addresses=[Address(type='home',
                                       city='Amsterdam'),
                               Address(type='work',
                                       street='Spear St',
                                       city='SF')])
    guido.put()
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'

    self.response.write('name: %s\n' % guido.name)
    for address in guido.addresses:
      self.response.write('  type: %s\n' % address.type)
      self.response.write('  city: %s\n' % address.city)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)
  ], debug=True)
```

So obviously you're doing something wrong in your actual application and you might not storing the actual values correctly.

Comment: Thanks @Lipis, maybe after a nights sleep I will be able to solve this. will update.

Comment: OK, Due to the structure of my app the Contact is created in advance of the addresses, The app queries Contact, using Contact.get_by_id(int(contact_id)) as shown in my example, then adds the addresses with data from a form very similar to whats shown above. If I display the addresses just after guido.put() using the current reference to Contact ie 'guido' I can see them, as you have shown. Its when I Later query this that I seem to not be able to see addresses? I will try and replicate the code we are using in this simple example to mimic my code structure more exactly.I will do this later.