# google appengine db to ndb migration error: 'model_from_protobuf'

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-ndb, google-app-engine-python, djangoappengine

I am in the process of migrating from from db to ndb and i am getting an error in that i do not understand. It is coming from the following line:

`return [db.model_from_protobuf(entity_pb.EntityProto(x)) for x in data]`

The full error is below:

File

```
"/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/174489198b39d9fb/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/174489198b39d9fb/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/174489198b39d9fb/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
return handler.dispatch()
File "/base/data/home/apps/s~proj-/44.427741511160881878/handlers/handler.py", line 329, in dispatch
super(SiteHandler, self).dispatch()
File "/base/data/home/apps/s~proj-/44.427741511160881878/handlers/handler.py", line 130, in dispatch
webapp2.RequestHandler.dispatch(self)
File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/174489198b39d9fb/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/174489198b39d9fb/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
return method(*args, **kwargs)
File "/base/data/home/apps/s~proj-/44.427741511160881878/handlers/site_handlers.py", line 112, in get
self.get_not_logged_in()
File "/base/data/home/apps/s~proj-/44.427741511160881878/handlers/site_handlers.py", line 139, in get_not_logged_in
(missions_memcache_key, missions_expiration)])
File "/base/data/home/apps/s~proj/44.427741511160881878/utils.py", line 368, in cache_get_multi
missing_items[k] = deserialize_entities(missing_items[k])
File "/base/data/home/apps/s~proj-/44.427741511160881878/utils.py", line 277, in deserialize_entities
return [db.model_from_protobuf(entity_pb.EntityProto(x)) for x in data]
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'model_from_protobuf'
```

What can i change this to fix it? The documentation has not really been so helpful
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/db_to_ndb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The errors seems to come from the fact that you are still using `db` instead of `ndb` in that line.

According to [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.datastore_types#google.appengine.api.datastore_types.EmbeddedEntity), you should be able to decode from the protobuf using `ndb.LocalStructuredProperty`. I have found [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21212348/10810527) where OP uses the aforementioned method to read from protobuf.

I have also found a [public repository](https://github.com/dound/gae-sessions/blob/4bfd6f5e5e5c543ac616faa5f680ecf07a84f4be/gaesessions/__init__.py#L239-L245) where it uses `pb_to_entity` to do the transformation but I'm not fully confident about this because of the lack of comments. You should try both methods and see which one do you prefer.

Comment: sorry, that is my fault, i did not clarify that i imported `ndb` as `db` as to make the migration faster

Comment: Could you try the methods I attached though?

Comment: hey, thank  the `ndb.LocalStructureProperty` seems to have worked. the next error i am getting is `AttributeError: 'PickleProperty' object has no attribute '_db_get_value'`. Do you think this is related?

Comment: Is it being triggered on your code or the library? According to [the source code](https://googleapis.dev/python/python-ndb/latest/_modules/google/cloud/ndb/model.html) the method `_db_get_value()` is deprecated. This inconsistency can happen if you are using libraries with incompatible versions.

Comment: ok, makes sense. Sorry i am new and have a hard time understanding how to solve these issues. So if i find out that it is deprecated, how would i go about to see what replaces it?

Comment: I don't know that. Maybe if you find an error on a public library it could be worth to open an issue on the GitHub repository and they may solve it or offer you a workaround (or you create a PR to fix it). Maybe you find the solution on another StackOverflow question.